# RxJS .pipe doesn't working as expected on Safari

Tags: safari, angular8, rxjs6

currently I've an implementation using Angular 8 and RxJS 6.5.2 that works perfectly on Google Chrome, but in Safari it's returning an error without sense for me. Below I'll share a fragment of this implementation:

```
public getLoggedEmployee(): Observable<any> {
        if (this.employee) {
            return of(this.employee);
        }

        return this.authenticationService
            .getAuthenticatedUser()
            .pipe(
                tap(user => this.authUser = user),
                flatMap(user => this.findOneById(user.id)),
                map((employee) => {
                    this.employee = _.merge(employee.data, { user: this.authUser });

                    return this.employee;
                })
            );
    }
```

How I said, in Chrome works fine, but in Safari I've this error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.id')`

For some reason on the `flatMap` action, the value for `user` still **undefined**, I can't imagine why. I did a check for compilerOption target of the project, currently using `es5`, checked for some missing polyfills for Safari but not luck so far.

If some one have any idea that can help me to find a solution I'll appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure your service is returning a valid user? try putting `console.log(user)` in the tap

Comment: Yes, I'm totally sure, as I said in Google Chrome works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok in my Safari (Catalina 10.15.4, Safari 13.1 15609.1.20.111.8).

How about return a mock data (like `of({ id: 1 })`) in `getAuthenticatedUser` ? Will the error still occur ?